# C# .NET Class member type based on another member type

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, class

There is a Class define a geometry which includes 2 members, "type", and "coordinates"

```
[DataContract]
public class geometry
{
    [DataMember]
    public string type = "LineString";

    [DataMember]
    public float coordinates;

}
```

Is there a way that the coordinates member type can be dynamically defined based on the value of "type"? for example, if the "type" is "MultiLineString" the coordinates type will be string?

Comment: You always have the option to use `dynamic` or `object` as the type, though I would hope there are better alternatives. I'll give an example using generics that I think is better.

Comment: are you using WCF, if so add it as a tag, most nice .net design don't work for WCF, so you need a WCF expert to provide the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not possible. The closest you could get is to define a generic class like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class geometry<T> where T : struct
{
    [DataMember]
    public T coordinates;
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
var geom = new geometry<float>();
geom.coordinates = 1.0f;
```

If you really want to have the type member there, say, for serialization purposes, you could use something like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class geometry<T> where T : struct
{
    [DataMember]
    public readonly string type = typeof(T).Name;

    [DataMember]
    public T coordinates;
}

var geom = new geometry<float>();
Console.WriteLine(geom.type); // Single
```

Comment: Be forewarned, since you're using these as data contract definitions, instances of generics cannot be serialized without the generic being closed. e.g., you cannot have an operation contract contain a method that returns `Geometry<T>` or accepts one as a parameter. You can, however, have service methods return and/or receive a `Geometry<int>` or `Geometry<string>`, etc.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot That's a good point. I've never tried it, but I've always wondered, would a `KnownType` attribute be able to get around that limitation?